# Java equivalent of c#'s MakeGenericType to create instance of unknown generic type

Tags: java, generics

Its been a long time since I have touched Java.  But given the following C# syntax, is it possible to create an unknown instance of a generic type in java?

```
public void Send(object message)
{
    Type requestType = message.GetType();
    ReceiverWrapper receiverInstance = (ReceiverWrapper)
            Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ReceiverWrapper<>).MakeGenericType(requestType));

    // do something with the receiver...
}
```

So the idea being `Object message` is of type `Message1`.  I want to create an instance of `ReceiverWrapper<Message1>`.

I don't want to use generics in method signature - ala `public <T> void Send(T message)` as I already understand this in Java.  I am curious whether we can extract type information from Object and create a generic based on that type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things to unpack here, first of all var is not a generic type. Var will be replaced by an actual type at compile time so if you want to use generics you probably shouldnt use var.

```
public <T> void Send(T message)
{
    ReceiverWrapper<T> receiverInstance = new ReceiverWrapper<>();

// do something with the receiver...
}
```

I'm not entirely sure what you want to do with it but something like this?

Comment: Copy and pasted code. Yep, I am aware of var, trust me! Updated question to reflect this and what I want - It HAS to be object in this scenario - extract the type from the Object

Comment: @Andez ok so how about ReceiverWrapper<?> instance = new ReceiverWrapper<>();

Comment: It compiles - so just looking into it more thanks.  Just wrapping my stuff up in a test to see how it all works.

Comment: @Andez as jon pointed out generics dont exist in run time, they are there to help you write code that doesnt break so giving ReceiverWrapper a type dynamically doesnt make sense. With <?> you skip this whole process and say "I dont know what im going to put in or get out" but working with generics would make better code.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to create an instance of `ReceiverWrapper<Message1>`.

There's no such thing in Java. There's just `ReceiverWrapper`. Java generics are *mostly* a compile-time artifact. For example, if you have a field which is of type `List<String>` you can determine that with reflection - but an *object* isn't an instance of `ArrayList<String>`, it's just an instance of `ArrayList`.

Comment: Thanks @Jon...  I'm missing C# already...  Its going to be a long slog.  Are there any recommended readings around generics and java?

Comment: @Andez: Not that I'd have read in the last 10 years, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

> „*…is it possible to create an unknown instance of a generic type in java?…*“

Yes. It is possible. But only if certain preconditions can be guaranteed (*see the comments in the code*).

I outline *the gist* of the technique with the snippets below. [*The working experiment can be run online*](https://www.browxy.com#USER_308574)…

```
{
    ...
    Optional< Object > parameterizedType ...

    TypeVariable< ? > typeVars[ ] ...

    /* Precondition #1: target MUST be a generic class */
    if( typeVars.length == 0 ){ throw new NotAGenericTypeException( ); }
  
    /* Precondition #2: target MUST expose a constructor that's declared to take arguments
     * whose type is that of those declared in the generic class's type parameter section */
    if( isConstructorCompatible ( target, typeVars ) ){
        
        try{ 
            parameterizedType = Optional.of( target.getClass( ).getConstructors( )[0].newInstance( typeArgs ) );
        } catch( ReflectiveOperationException roe ){ roe.printStackTrace( ); }
    }
    
    return parameterizedType;
}
```

> „*…So the idea being `Object message` is of type `Message1`. I want to create an instance of `ReceiverWrapper<Message1>`…*“

Although your question's *`Send(Object)`* method returns *`void`*, to make my proof of concept more testable my experimental implementation returns an instance of the parameterized type…

```
...
public Optional< Object > send( Object message ){ 
    return parameterizer.parameterize( ReceiverWrapper.class, message );    
}
...
```

[***Usage example***](https://www.browxy.com#USER_308574)…

```
...
/* Set up a test of @Andez's use case  */
Object sos = new Message( "Friends of space, how are you all? Have you eaten yet? Come visit us if you have time." );
    
/* The class under test */
ProofOfConcept voyager = new ProofOfConcept( );
    
/* Exercise the method under test */
Optional< Object > type  voyager.send( sos );
    
/* Prepare the outcome of the parameterization done in the previous voyager.send( ) call */
ReceiverWrapper< Message > oumuamua = type.map( raw -> (ReceiverWrapper< Message >)raw ).orElseThrow( AssertionError::new );
    
/* Leverage the compiler's type checking */
Message fromSpace = oumuamua.getMessage( );
    
/* Verify that the expected type returned by send( ) is the type of the type argument */
assert ((Object)fromSpace) instanceof Message : "EXPERIMENT FAILED";
...
```

Results of the experiment…

```
Message [ payload: Friends of space, how are you all? Have you eaten yet? Come visit us if you have time. ]
             EXPERIMENT SUCCESSFUL
```

And they said it couldn't be done :)